# A paragraph from a book by Däniken

Tags: translation

I'll change the subject of the topic once I know where the problem is.

I am reading Erich von Däniken's Götterdämmerung. On p32 I have come across a passage that doesn't make sense to me.

> Obwohl man früher annahm, dass die Ruinen das Werk der Inkas seien, als Festung für ihre Kriege, hat man jetzt erkannt, dass sie im Gegenteil ein Werk von vor der Sintflut sind... [Hervorhebung EvD]. Wäre es nämlich ein Werk der Inkas, so tief gegraben, so hätten nicht einmal die Spanier ein so wunderbares Gebäude von solcher Wucht herstellen können.

The first sentence explains why the work couldn't have been done by the Incas. Then the second sentence says, if they were done by the Incas, then even the Spaniards couldn't have done them... which makes no sense at all.

Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: I think it's pretty futile trying to find logic in Däniken's works. It is unfortunate that this author was so popular (and still is, as it seems).

Comment: Wo ist denn die Hervorhebung EvDs abgeblieben? Der erste Satz klärt mitnichten, wieso es kein Werk der Inkas sein kann, sondern behauptet lediglich es sei älter als die Sintflut - offenbar hält er diese für ein globales, historisches und einzigartiges Ereignis (die S.). Der zweite Satz ist unlogisches Kauderwelsch. Wieso soll die Fähigkeit der Spanier ein solches Gebäude zu bauen davon abhängen, ob die Inkas es konnten? Ich vermute auch nicht, dass Satz 2 mit Schweizerdeutsch erklärt werden kann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wäre es nämlich ein Werk der Inkas, so tief gegraben, so hätten nicht
>   einmal die Spanier ein so wunderbares Gebäude von solcher Wucht
>   herstellen können.

This really is a gem.

What he means is "ein Werk *aus der Zeit* der Inkas" - in these times nobody, neither Incas nor Spaniards, were capable of such constructions.

It shows that he was genuinely excited. (politely said)